# Insert into mysql specific situation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a strange situation in mysql, So I have table witch have multiple columns, one of it is specific. This columns is `specific INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL`.
So If I write in sql : 
`INSERT INTO infos_game (id_game,specific) VALUES (0, 12)` ---- doesn't work
If I write : 
``` INSERT INTO infos_game (id_game,``specific``) VALUES (0, 12) ```----- it works, so if specific is between `` works fine. What is the problem ? Help me please. Thx in advance.
If is a reserved word, how to insert in database from php, I tried :

```
$o_infos_game_user_registered = new \Entity\Cluster\InfosGame(array(
                        'id_game'        => $game->id_game,
                        'specific'    => $game->specific,
        ),
        );
        $o_infos_game_user_registered->save();
```

But I get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that *specific* is a reserved word. To use a reserved word you need to use back ticks (``) otherwise the query will fail.

**Reading Material**

**MySQL Keywords** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Hit `CTRL + F` then type *specific* and it will highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

Executing queries with reserved words can be done in 3 different ways

1) Rename columns into non reserved word

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" RENAME COLUMN "column 1" TO "column 2";
```

2) Use back ticks in queries (``)

```
INSERT INTO infos_game (`id_game`,`specific`) VALUES (0,12)
```

3. Use inserts without specifying columns (when u insert data which contains all columns )

```
//old query
INSERT INTO infos_game (id_game,specific) VALUES (0, 12)
//new query
INSERT INTO infos_game VALUES (0, 12)
```

Comment: **2** - those aren't back ticks.